# Failed to initialize dev toolbar app Audit (astro:audit)

Tags: astrojs

### Problem

I encountered this error when upgrading to the latest version of Astro. What should I do to solve it?

### Astro Version

```
Astro                    v4.4.15
Node                     v20.10.0
System                   macOS (arm64)
Package Manager          npm
Output                   static
Adapter                  none
Integrations             @astrojs/vue
                         @astrojs/tailwind
```

### error text:

```
09:57:28 [ERROR] [toolbar] Failed to initialize dev toolbar app Audit (astro:audit):
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'requiredProps' of 'roles.get(...)' as it is undefined.
    at Object.match (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_@types+node@20.11.25_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/client/dev-toolbar/apps/audit/a11y.js?v=935f82d6:486:17)
    at lint (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_@types+node@20.11.25_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/client/dev-toolbar/apps/audit/index.js?v=935f82d6:48:28)
    at async Object.init (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_@types+node@20.11.25_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/client/dev-toolbar/apps/audit/index.js?v=935f82d6:30:5)
    at async AstroDevToolbar.initApp (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.pnpm/astro@4.4.15_@types+node@20.11.25_typescript@5.4.2/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/client/dev-toolbar/toolbar.js?v=935f82d6:323:7)
```

### error screenshot:

[image]